# how to fix Manager isn't accessible via Words instances error?

Tags: django-models, sum

I want to sum all objects which have the (freq) name when I execute this code it doesn't work but instead, it raises this error:  **Manager isn't accessible via Words instances**

I actually understood later what is this error talking about but I couldn't put the solution. all I knew that there is a function called (aggregate) but I can't use it because I need to exclude a specific query from execution.

this is what the code looks like:

models.py

```
class Words(models.Model):
    freq = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

def sum_freq(self):
    freqs = []
    words = self.objects.all().exclude(tag='Pu')
    for word in words:
        freqs.append(word.freq)
    summation = sum(freqs)
    return summation


def percent_n(self):
    words = self.objects.all().exclude(tag='Pu')
    percent_list = []
    for word in words:
        percent_n = (word.freq / word.sum_freq) * 100
        percent_n = round(percent_n, 2)
        percent_list.append(percent_n)
    return percent_list
```

I need to call sum_freq into percent_n by sum the freq query first then returned to the percent_n function. I can't know until now if the percent_n function works or not because I didn't test the freq function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not work with `self.objects`, but `Words.objects`, or `type(self).objects`:

```
class Words(models.Model):
    # …

    def sum_freq(self):
        freqs = []
        words = type(self).objects.all().exclude(tag='Pu')
        for word in words:
            freqs.append(word.freq)
        summation = sum(freqs)
        return summation

    def percent_n(self):
        words = type(self).objects.all().exclude(tag='Pu')
        percent_list = []
        for word in words:
            percent_n = (word.freq / word.sum_freq) * 100
            percent_n = round(percent_n, 2)
            percent_list.append(percent_n)
        return percent_list
```

Since the `sum_freq` and `percent_n` however never really deal with the `self` object, you might want to convert it to a `classmethod`, by using a `@classmethod` decorator:

```
class Words(models.Model):
    # …

    @classmethod
    def sum_freq(cls):
        freqs = []
        words = cls.objects.exclude(tag='Pu')
        for word in words:
            freqs.append(word.freq)
        summation = sum(freqs)
        return summation

    @classmethod
    def percent_n(cls):
        words = cls.objects.exclude(tag='Pu')
        percent_list = []
        for word in words:
            percent_n = (word.freq / word.sum_freq) * 100
            percent_n = round(percent_n, 2)
            percent_list.append(percent_n)
        return percent_list
```

That being said, you do not need to aggregate yourself, you can easily aggregate with Django's [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Round

class Words(models.Model):
    # …

    @classmethod
    def sum_freq(cls):
        return cls.objects.exclude(tag='Pu').aggregate(
            summation=Sum('freq')
        )['summation'] or 0

    @classmethod
    def percent_n(cls):
        summation = cls.sum_freq()
        return list(
            cls.objects.exclude(tag='Pu').values_list(
                 Round(10000*F('freq')/summation)/100,
                 flat=True
            )
        )
```

Comment: I have a little confusion around using cls so my first question is why cls instead of self if self is acting as a proxy of a class itself? the second is: when I execute the functions that you gave me the page hangs and loading still works but no result as if a program enters to loop.

Comment: @MedoAbdin: `cls` is a reference to the class object, this is passed by the `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: @MedoAbdin: exactly which script hangs. That with the `for` loops will likely be unscalable, since if the number of records increases, it will result in more bandwidth from the database to the Django/Python layer.

Comment: so, How can I resolve that problem it's likely to increase the volume of queries in the database more hence will cause the hang and will slow loading page How can I fix that? could you help?

Comment: @MedoAbdin: you second item that calculates the percentage per `Word` is inherently unscalable, so you will eventually need pagination for that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/). As for the sum, normally by using an `.aggregate(...)` this will work quite efficiently, since this is done in *one* query, and the query itself only returns the sum.

Comment: I was thinking of pagination too. thanks for the help @Willem